# Como hacer este layout con grid css

Tags: html, css, grid

quería saber como podía lograr este grid:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo esto armado pero no me funciona:

```
 &__rocket{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
            grid-gap: 20px;
            grid-auto-flow: row dense;

            :first-child {
                grid-column: 1 / 3;
            }
            
            :last-child {
                grid-column: 3 / 5;
                grid-row: 2 / 3;
            }
        }
```

y se ve asi [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Describiendo cada celda del grid de forma manual puede lograrse. Mira esta solución

```css
<style>
.item1 { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 3; height:100px }
.item2 { grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4; }
.item3 { grid-area: 1 / 4 / 2 / 5; }
.item4 { grid-area: 2 / 3 / 4 / 5; }
.item5 { grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2; }
.item6 { grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 3; }
.item7 { grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4; }
.item8 { grid-area: 2 / 4 / 3 / 5; }

.grid-caja {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 150px;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  background-color: green;padding:15px
}

.grid-caja > div {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  text-align: center;
  padding:15px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="grid-caja">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>  
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>

</div>
```

Al poner las imágenes debes cuidar las dimensiones o ajustarlas mediante estilos.

Comment: El número 1 solo recoge una fracción en lugar de dos

Comment: Puedes verlo en https://creatuweb.espaciolatino.com/ejemplos/grid.htm. He ajustado tamaños con las imágenes que he usado. Mira el código fuente de la página para ver como queda. He usado una imagen con distintos tamaños, la mayor 600 ocupa dos columnas por tanto el ancho de columna es 300 más los espacios entre celdas, igual con el alto son 442 más el ancho entre celdas.

Comment: Me sirvio! Muchas gracias